# Google Colab won't unzip the zipfile

Tags: shell, zip, google-colaboratory

I used to be able to unzip my 5GB zipfile and work on it easily.
However now I get a Google Drive error:
error:  zipfile read error

I used to be able to work on it just 2 days ago.

I tried using 7zip as suggested somewhere else, however it also did not work.

```
from google.colab import drive;
drive.mount('/content/drive/', force_remount=True);

!unzip 'drive/My Drive/tmp/somefile.zip'
```

and the error is like the following,

```
inflating: somefile/images/P0003__1__0___23.png  error:  zipfile read error
```

Is there any suggestion to force unzip this file into given directory?

**Note: zipfile works totally fine in local. (decompresses without any error)**

Comment: Sorry for your pain, but StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common cause of this error is exceeding the Drive transfer quota for the file.

https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/8axoev/question_for_a_google_drive_guru_any_idea_what/

Transfer quotas reset over time, so I'd try again later. A tip to avoid unnecessarily consuming transfer quota is to copy the file from Drive to the local disk before unzipping the file, e.g.,

```
!cp /content/drive/My\ Drive/tmp/somefile.zip /content
!unzip /content/somefile.zip
```

Comment: When I tried to download the zipfile, it did not let me (This is how I understood something was wrong with Google Drive)

So if I copy the file to local disk (which is content directory) this would not let me exceed the quota?

And also I guess the content is the home directory of google colab?